# Magento 2: Redirect user to login if not access on store view

Tags: magento2

I am using plugin for Magento 2:
[Store Login Access](https://www.itoris.com/magento-login-management.html), but I am facing some issue.
**Consider an example:**
There is a user who is having access on store view English and France but not having access on Store View Spanish.
So when he tries to access store view Spanish, it shows error:

> There has been an error processing your request

I want the user, to be redirected to the login page if he is not having access.
I have explored couple of options on admin panel but not getting exact way to do it. Also, I am new to Magento so I am not sure which file I need to edit to fix this.